# Can I save an iex command alias in .iex.exs file?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

In iex, I'd like to break out of a block using `#iex:break`, but I find that annoying to type. Can it be aliased? Preferably, I'd be able to save this in my user's `.iex.exs` file for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the source code, [`#iex:break`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/57ee3e811dc90752c0ffb72099b587b5cf1b54f3/lib/iex/lib/iex/evaluator.ex#L59-L81) is hardcoded in `IEx.Evaluator` and therefore cannot be neither substituted nor aliased.

That is probably because the shorter *breaker* would have many false positives in the [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) code.

The only possibility would be to patch `IEx.Evaluator` code and compile [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) yourself.